# Object moving around a pill shape button border is not following the correct path

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have created a pill-shaped button (border-radius of 55px) and I have put an external border to which I have added a circle using css pseudo-classes.
I have also created an animation using css keyframes, so that the circle moves along the outer border created for that button, but the moment the circle reaches the beginning of the round border of the button, it behaves in a strange way and does not perform the semicircular movement it is supposed to have.

For that case I tried using sin and cos function to calculate the 'top' and 'left' coordinates of the object based on the radius of the semicircle which in this case would be 55px.

This is the code I have created for that button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      :root {
        --PI: 3.14159265358979;
        --radius: 55px;
      }

      .main-hero__cta-button {
        border: 5px solid white;
        padding: 5px 45px;
        border-radius: 55px;
        background-color: #06509A;
        font-weight: 300;
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        transition: background-color .5s ease, box-shadow .5s ease;
        box-shadow: #06509A 0px 1px 1px, #06509A 0px 0px 0px 1px;
      }

      .main-hero__cta-button a {
        color: white;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        line-height: 1.3em;
      }

      .main-hero__cta-button:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: -24%;
        left: 6%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        height: 8px;
        width: 8px;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: background-color .5s ease;
        animation: moveCircleBefore 6s linear infinite;
      }

      @keyframes moveCircleBefore {
        0%, 100% {
          top: -24%;
          left: 6%;
        }
        12.5% {
          top: -24%;
          left: 36%;
        }
        25% {
          top: -24%;
          left: 66%;
        }
        37% {
          top: -24%;
          left: 94%;
        }
        37.5% {
          top: calc(-24% + var(--radius) * cos(0.5turn));
          left: calc(94% + var(--radius) * sin(0.5turn));
        }
        50% {
          top: 104%;
          left: 94%;
        }
        62.5% {
          top: 104%;
          left: 66%;
        }
        75% {
          top: 104%;
          left: 36%;
        }
        87% {
          top: 104%;
          left: 6%;
        }
        87.5% {
          top: calc(104% - var(--radius) * cos(0.5turn));
          left: calc(6% + var(--radius) * sin(0.5turn));
        }
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section style="padding: 6rem">
    <div class="main-hero__cta-inner main-hero__cta-button">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Get started now</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know if someone can help me because I really do not understand what I can do in this case to get the animation to perform correctly.

Thanks in advance for the collaboration of the community.

Greetings.